I can't delete all data in Google Play services
I'm using an Honor 5C with Android 7.0 and Google Play services 23.50.14. I'm out of storage on my phone, with only a few applications and photos. I noticed that Google Play services contains 2.48 GB of data.

but when I go in the "Manage space" menu, it says that deleting all the data would clear 115 MB.

How can I delete all of the 2.48 GB?

If you have adb access to the phone you could try the command adb pm clear com.google.android.gms may be this way of clearing app cache works better.
